# I find myself writing wrapper functions purely to await on async function. How to avoid this pattern?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mvvm, async-await

I'm new to async programming, in C#. My motivation for using async is to avoid locking UI threads in win form applications, without needing to make use of a bunch of background workers, or explicit threads, etc. That's my understanding currently, anyway.

In order to await on an awaitable function, the calling function needs to be async. Well, I've found myself constantly using the following pattern ...

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
  private Thing m_thing;

  public SomeViewModel()
  {
    ReloadThing();
  }

  public Thing Thing
  {
    get {
      return m_thing;
    }

    protected set {
      m_thing = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public async void ReloadThing()
  {
     Thing = await FetchThing();
  }

  private async Task<Thing> FetchThing()
  {
    // entity framework code
    return await DbSet<Things>.SingleAsync();
  }
}
```

It's basically some hacked together attempt at an MVVM style view model for my view (Form).

But, the pattern is the async wrapper function simply so I can use await. Is there a better approach that I should be using here?

Comment: Are you asking if you need the FetchThing method? Or are you wondering if there is an easier way than having async on both methods?

Comment: I guess the over-all question is whether there's a more direct way to load data in a non-blocking way within a view model like this, so that a view (win form) can bind to a property backed by that async data? That's about the most specific-to-my-situation question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess the over-all question is whether there's a more direct way to load data in a non-blocking way within a view model like this, so that a view (win form) can bind to a property backed by that async data? That's about the most specific-to-my-situation question.

You may find my article on [async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) useful. In it, I introduce a data-bindable wrapper for `Task<T>`, which removes a lot of the boilerplate code around having asynchronous code update data bindings (as well as properly handling error situations, etc).

An updated version of that code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/blob/f2bcf210872de28d4779548ac5073e33980f2080/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async/NotifyTask.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Async is annoying like that. As soon as one method is asynchronous and you want to await it, then that forces the next method, and the next method, and the next method to also use async until you: a) reach the top or b) find a spot where you're willing to `Wait()`.

I don't think you're doing anything wrong; except that, you don't need `FetchThing()` to accomplish your example. But I'm not sure if you have FetchThing there just to illustrate the point. If not, you could combine the body of `FetchThing()` with `ReloadThing()` to make the below:

```
public async void ReloadThing()
{
   Thing = await DbSet<Things>.SingleAsync();
}
```

Otherwise, what you have looks correct to me.

Comment: I think user497745 is on target. I would only add that you could probably change async void to async Task, which would support more complete exception handling and possibly cancellation, if you need it. I was taught to never write async void unless it's an event handler.